# Using fitted lagged variable as dependent variable in a new regression?

Tags: regression, time-series, least-squares, exponential-distribution, trend

Suppose I have regression like this;
$y[t] = a * exp(b*y[t-1])$

From this regression, I get;

$\bar y = y - residuals$

What happens if I regress a new regression like this?
$y[t] = c * exp(d*ybar[t-1])$

Is there any special meaning for this curve and estimation?